Anti-Hermitian Hamiltonians in Quantum Mechanics and Open Systems
The Schrodinger equation (SE) with a Hermitian operator $H$ generates unitary evolution, and it is well-known that plenty of quantum processes can be described by SE and appropriately chosen $H$. That is,
$$
\frac{d\psi}{dt} = -i H \psi(t) \tag{1}
$$
generates a unitary evolution that can describe some quantum process.
However, what if we have
$$
\frac{d\psi}{dt} = -i (H + \tilde H)\psi(t) = \sigma_x \psi(t),\tag{2}
$$
where $H = 0$ and $\tilde H = i \sigma_x$. In other words, the system's Hamiltonian $H$ is zero, and we have an additional anti-Hermitian term $\tilde H$.
I understand that this evolution is not unitary, but does this represent a physical process? I read that this has to do with quantum open systems and gain/loss processes.
Reading about open quantum systems, I learned that we can define two Kraus operators
\begin{align}
K_0 &= I - i Hdt -\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x dt = I - \frac{1}{2}I dt,\\
K_1 &= \sqrt{dt}\sigma_x. \tag{3}
\end{align}
In the above, $H=0$. Also, $K_1$ represents a jump over time interval $dt$, and $K_0$ describes the evolution in the absence of a jump over time interval dt. However, what if I have the following Kraus operators
\begin{align}
K_0 &= I -i(H + \tilde H)dt -\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x dt = I + \sigma_x dt - \frac{1}{2}I dt, \\
K_1 &= \sqrt{dt}\sigma_x. \tag{4}
\end{align}
As before, $H=0$ and $\tilde H = i \sigma_x$. I figured that these Kraus operators do not satisfy the completeness relation $K_0^{\dagger}K_0 + K_1^{\dagger}K_1 \neq I + O(dt^2)$, but maybe it is not a problem.
Question:
Can the presence of the anti-Hermitian term $\tilde H$ in Eq. 2 and Eq. 4 be justified or intuitively explained?

Edit: I got several enlightning comments and answers and decided to provide more details to my question.
Assuming $H=0$, using $K_0$ and $K_1$ in Eq.3, we can derive the standard master equation (the one I saw in books, at least).
\begin{align}
\rho(t+dt) &= K_0\rho(t)K_0^{\dagger} + K_1 \rho(t) K_1^{\dagger} \\
&= \left( I -\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x dt\right)\rho(t)\left( I -\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x dt \right) + \sigma_x\rho(t)\sigma_x^{\dagger}\\
&= \rho(t) -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\}dt + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger}dt. \tag{5}
\end{align}
The above can be rearranged into
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\} + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger} \tag{6}
$$
If $H\neq 0$ we would have
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -i[H, \rho(t)] -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\} + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger} \tag{7}
$$
As stated in the answer by JudahReynolds, we can rearrange the equation further to obtain anti-Hermitian Hamiltonian $H_{eff}$ as
$$H_{eff} = H - \frac{i}{2}\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x.$$
Then, the evolution of the system can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -i(H_{eff}\rho- \rho H_{eff}^\dagger) + \sigma_x \rho \sigma_x^{\dagger}. \tag{8}
\end{equation}
So far, nothing deviates from what I've seen in books.
The issue is that if I now define $K_0$ and $K_1$ as in Eq. 4, the master equation comes out quite differently. We get one extra term (in red), which does not comply with the Lindblad form:
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -i[H, \rho(t)] + \color{red}{\left \{\sigma_x,\rho(t)\right \}} -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\} + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger} \tag{9}
$$
We can also rewrite this as
\begin{align}
\frac{d\rho}{dt} &= -i[H + i \sigma_x, \rho(t)] -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\} + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger} \\
&= -i[H + \tilde H, \rho(t)] -\frac{1}{2}\{\sigma_x^{\dagger}\sigma_x, \rho(t)\} + \sigma_x \rho(t) \sigma_x^{\dagger}. \tag{9}
\end{align}
The effective Hamiltonian is then
$$
H_{eff} = H +\color{red}{i\sigma_x} -\frac{i}{2}\sigma_x \sigma_x^{\dagger} = H + \color{red}{\tilde{H}} -\frac{i}{2}\sigma_x \sigma_x^{\dagger}.\tag{10}
$$
So again, I face the issue of understanding and justifying the presence of $\tilde H$ in the master equation [Eq. 9] and effective Hamiltonian [Eq. 10]. These equations do not fit the standard definitions of master equations. So perhaps by having this extra term, I break some physical rules or make the equation "unphysical".

I think this question and accepted answer can help.  This is in the context of a quantum master equation of Lindblad form (which is one way to treat open systems where the system-environment coupling is "weak"), but I imagine there's a similar interpretation in the formalism you've outlined in your post. In that answer, $\tilde{H} = iC_n^{\dagger}C_n$, and it's this piece that determines decay of probability "away" from the initial states and "into" different jump channels.

@march, thanks for the link. Yes, the question you posted is related, but it does not address the presence of the extra term $\tilde H$. The Kraus operators I defined can be used to define the Lindblad equation, but it will also have a non-conventional extra term involving $\tilde H$.

What you are doing is equivalent to imaginary time evolution. Under this evolution the system will decay to the ground state of the operator $i\tilde{H}$. It doesn't, to my knowledge, have a direct interpretation for open systems but can be related to modelling systems at finite temperature

To answer your first question, an anti-Hermitian operator absolutely can describe a physical process. Note that the evolution of the system you are interested and the surrounding as a whole still obey the Schrödinger equation and the evolution is indeed unitary.
A good example would be that of 1 system qubit and infinite bath qubits. Say they have a $({\sigma}- \otimes {\sigma}+)+({\sigma}+ \otimes {\sigma}-)$ interaction between the system and bath qubits. The physical process this describes is the system qubit losing energy to its surrounding.

There seem to be two schools of thought regarding non-Hermitian Hamiltonians. This review by Roccati et al. is a good resource.
The first approach recognizes that such non-Hermitian Hamiltonians can actually possess real eigenvalues in spite of their lack of hermiticity. The presence of (unbroken) parity-time symmetry forces the Hamiltonian to have real eigenvalues even if it is not Hermitian. However, the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian are no longer orthogonal, and some of the usual formalism of quantum mechanics must change. There is an entire branch of research that takes parity-time symmetry to be fundamental instead of hermiticity (fittingly called $\cal{P}\cal{T}$-symmetric quantum mechanics).
The second approach is more similar to what you and the other answer have noted. In the presence of noise and measurements, quantum mechanical time evolution takes the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\rho] + \sum_\alpha \gamma_\alpha(L_\alpha\rho L_\alpha^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{L_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha,\rho\})
\end{equation}
for jump operators $L_\alpha$ (similar to your $K$ operators), a hermitian Hamiltonian $H$, and a density matrix $\rho$. Now, we can instead write this as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}(H_{eff}\rho- \rho H_{eff}^\dagger) + \sum_\alpha \gamma_\alpha L_\alpha\rho L_\alpha^\dagger,
\end{equation}
where $H_{eff} \equiv H - \frac{i}{2}\sum_\alpha \gamma_\alpha L_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha$. $H_{eff}$ can be checked to be a non-hermitian operator. In a semiclassical limit, we can neglect the $\sum_\alpha \gamma_\alpha L_\alpha\rho L_\alpha^\dagger$ term, so that the time evolution is given by:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}(H_{eff}\rho- \rho H_{eff}^\dagger),
\end{equation}
which is similar to the closed time evolution equation (Von Neumann equation) for a density matrix. In this way, we can obtain an effective non-Hermitian Hamiltonian, with loss and gain given by the anti-Hermitian component.
In short, non-Hermitian Hamiltonians are used to semiclassically model loss and gain in open systems. The anti-Hermitian component yields a non-unitary component to the time evolution.
In other settings, we can begin with $\cal{P}\cal{T}$-symmetric quantum mechanics, and have real eigenvalues and conservation of probability.

For your example given in eq. (3) and (4), we do not have that the (squared) Kraus operators sum to 1 as you already recognized. We can show that:
\begin{equation}
K_0^\dagger K_0 + K_1^\dagger K_1 = (I + \sigma_x \mathrm{dt} -
\dfrac{1}{2} I \mathrm{dt}) + I \mathrm{dt} = I + (\sigma_x + \frac{1}{2} I)\mathrm{dt},
\end{equation}
which clearly does not have the desired property. This leads to the problems you have noted.
In fact, your proposed Kraus operators are one way to obtain the traditional Lindblad master equation, but instead of fixing $H$ and $\tilde{H}$, we can only fix $H$. Then allowing arbitrary Jump operators $L_\alpha,$ the fact that $\sum_\alpha K_\alpha^\dagger K_\alpha = I$ forces us to have $\tilde{H} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_\alpha L_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha,$ which will give us the Lindblad equation!
I have been very heuristic in this derivation, and I would recommend filling in the steps with these notes of David Tong (Section 5, and in particular section 5.5). You can see it there with much more detail.

Thanks for sharing that! I wasn't aware of the semi-classical correspondence between the system/bath formalism and the non-unitary Schroedinger equation approach.

@JudahReynolds, thank you very much for a detailed and clear answer. I was able to rederive your first and second equations and obtain $H_{eff}$ when working with more "standard" definitions of $K_0$ and $K_1$ (see Eq. 3). But when $K_0$ is defined with an extra term $\tilde H:=L$ as in Eq. 4 the final result does not have the form of $H_{eff} = H -\frac{i}{2}L^{\dagger}L$. Specifically, with extra term $\tilde H = L$, the effective Hamiltonian is $H_{eff} = H + iL - \frac{i}{2}L^{\dagger}L$.

As you can see, there is an extra term $iL$. Since it does not fit the standard definition/form of the Lindblad equation, I struggle to justify it and wonder whether it is physically meaningful (I'm not a physicist, so it gets even harder for me). Perhaps having this extra term $iL$, I break some rules.

I've edited my question and added more details based on what you wrote.

I have edited the post, hopefully answering your question. Let me know if anything needs further clarification.

@JudahReynolds, thanks for extending your already great answer. I still don't know if Eq (9) and (10) where we have the extra term (anti-Hermitian term in red) are physically justifiable. Eq (9) and (10) are what interest me, but they do not comply with the standard definition of the master/Lindblad equation. Since, I know little physics, I can't tell if the equation form that I'm interested in physically possible. As such, I'm looking for a justification or explanation of whether it is "legal" to do something like that.

I read that Lindblad equation is equivalent to a CPTP map. The Eq. (9) is not TP but CP, which (I believe) is fine if we agree to post normalize the state after each step dt.

I believe that normalizing the state after each step dt is approximately the same as setting $\tilde{H}$ to 0, since that term has the effect of reducing the trace. In short, the quantum channel you write down (with $K_0,K_1$) is not a microscopic, fundamental description, but an effective one.


I understand that this evolution is not unitary, but does this represent a physical process?

If the evolution is not unitary then it is not guaranteed to preserve probability.
But, if it is unitary then
$$
\langle \Psi(t)|\Psi(t)\rangle=\langle \Psi(0)|U^\dagger (t)U(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle = \langle \Psi(0)|U^{-1}(t) U(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle = \langle \Psi(0)|\Psi(0)\rangle\;,
$$
where the unitary nature of the evolution is used in the second equality.
Non-unitary evolution can be introduced in an ad hoc way to account for a physical process like decay and other lossy processes.
For example, when a multi-particle system is approximated as an effective single-particle system, the effective single-particle "self-energy" can have an imaginary part that can represent loss of some kind (e.g., loss of energy to the environment).

Non-unitary does not imply not preserving probability. E.g. projection+normalization intervention is not unitary, but net probability is preserved at value 1.

I edited the answer @JánLalinský


Question: Can the presence of the anti-Hermitian term in Eq. 2 and Eq. 4 be justified or intuitively explained?

It seems that you proposed a mathematical model and is asking for a physical motivation, which is quite the opposite of what we do: usually we search for mathematical models to describe some physical situation, i.e., the physical motivation comes first.
As JudahReynolds answered, some non hermitian Hamiltonians could come as effective Hamiltonians when we consider open quantum systems. If I understood him correctly, your model could be obtained from a Lindblad equation considering $L =\sqrt{\sigma_x}$, so you will have $\tilde H$ as the effective Hamiltonian.
However, it seems to no satisfied you. So I'll argue in the opposite direction: your model doesn't have any physical meaning.
First, let's write what would be the time evolution operator for $\tilde H = i\sigma_x$. It will be
$$
U = e^{\sigma_x t} = \cosh(t) \mathbb I + \sinh(t) \sigma_x.
$$
Now, if we consider $\sigma_x |\pm\rangle = \pm |\pm\rangle$, we only need to verify what happens for this evolution operator for this eigenstates. We have
$$
U|-\rangle = e^{-t} |-\rangle 
$$
Which, as hft answered, could represent an ad hoc description of instability of the state $|-\rangle$ under this dynamics. The probability is not conserved, but it could be explained by considering that we are not taking account all degrees of freedom evolved in the dynamics. If we defined some state $|g\rangle$ representing the state of the system after decay, by normalization
$$
P_g(t) = 1-P_-(t) = 1 - e^{-2t}
$$
and we recover the total normalization of probability.
However, for the other eigenstate
$$
U|+\rangle = e^t|+\rangle
$$
And now, not only we have a probability that is not conserved, but increase with time. This could not be explained in the same manners as before. Worse than that, it diverges, which could not be explained by any physical means. The quantity
$$
P_+(t) = e^{2t}
$$
Is not even a probability, for $t>0$.
I couldn't find any physical meaning of this model. If there is some physical system described by such model, I really want to know it. But I bet that this Hamiltonian makes no sense, even effectively.
